UK Company liquidation implication on ex employee dependents
We moved to the UK under skilled worker visa almost 28 months ago.
We are family of 4 and my spouse is the main applicant, and myself and my 2 kids joined my spouse as dependents when we first entered the UK.
My spouse moved to another company after 1.5 years and his sponsorship was changed to new employer while we are on the same old visa that was issued for 3 years by the ex-employer.
Now we got to know the previous company we came to the UK initially is under liquidation, don’t know for what reasons.
My question is whether me and my kids who are still under the same old company visa have any sort of threat or implications to our immigration status or at the time of Visa Extension which is due next 6 months.

The official gov.uk website says this on your situation:

Your partner or children will need to apply separately to update their visa. They can either apply at the same time as you, or at any time before their current visa expires.

So it seems you do need to “update” your visa and the window hasn't closed for that. It's not completely clear to me whether the update will get you a fresh 3-year visa or if you need to apply for the update first and then apply again for an extension (which obviously makes a big difference as the fees are quite high).
